# Using Previous Directories in Reinstalling Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: boot, filesystem, 19.04, partitioning, mountpoint

I separated `/home` and `/opt` from `/` in the previous Ubuntu 19.04 installation. Now Ubuntu doesn't boot and I am trying to reinstall it. Can I use the previous `/home` and `/opt` in the current installation?

Comment: Yes.  Personally I always use 'something else' and pick my prior partitions; using this method I control the 'format' or **no-format**.  You can also not format you / partition; it'll note your extra packages installed, wipe system directories, install, then add-back additional packages you had before (if available) without touching your user files (unless you had format ticked).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Personally I always use 'something else' and pick my prior partitions; using this method I control the 'format' or no-format.

You don't need to format your / partition; it'll

- note your extra packages installed
- wipe system directories
- install
- add-back additional packages you had before (if available)

all without touching your user files (unless you had format checked). These options work the same if have a single partition too (with Ubuntu), but do be careful of the **format** checkbox.  (*and of course, firstly check your already created backups*)